# how can i embed php chart graphs into html

Tags: php, html, charts

i'm using PHP Graph Lib [PHPGraphLib](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/index.php)

i created some graphs , and all i need is to embed these graphs into html,,
you know, inside  and so on,,
every time i put the code within html it gives me errors

> The image “http://localhost/chart2.php” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

although without the html code , it works fine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your image code is in `chart2.php`, you embed it into html with an `img` tag:

`<img src="chart2.php" alt="This is a chart of x" />`